# Why isn't my return working for hailstone?

Tags: java, string, int

```
String hailstone(int n){
    if(n >= 1)
        if(n%2 == 0)
            n = (n/2);
        else 
            n = (n*3)+1;
    else 
        return n;
}
```

I know it needs to return a string and I tried `Integer.toString(n)` but this didn't work so I don't know what to do.

Comment: Why do you want to return a `String`? It would make more sense (to me, at least) to return an `int`.

Comment: Does it compile? Because I'm pretty sure it won't compile if only one path returns n.

Answer (score 4):

If you want the function to return the next Collatz number, remove the last `else`:

```
int hailstone(int n){
    if(n >= 1)
        if(n%2 == 0)
            n = (n/2);
        else 
            n = (n*3)+1;
    // else   <--- should be removed.
    return n;
}
```

and change the return value to `int` or do `return String.valueOf(n);`

If you then want to print the whole Hailstone series you do something like

```
int n = initialValue;
do {
    System.out.println(n);
    n = hailstone(n);
} while (n != 1);
```